# Difference between int var. var and &var

Tags: iphone, objective-c

HI guys,

Here is some code

```
 NSString *uid = [[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier];
 gameUniqueID = [uid hash];
 NSLog(@"gameUniqueID %d",gameUniqueID);
 NSLog(@"&gameUniqueID %d",&gameUniqueID);
```

The output is

```
gameUniqueID -1386422508
&gameUniqueID 1386832
```

Whats going on here? I though they would be the same.

Comment: @Kirill - that's irrelevant. &var will return a pointer to the memory occupied by var. You most certainly can do it, regardless of it being an object. var still occupies memory, and has an address.

Comment: Just realized what I've wrote. You're completely right. Of course you can

`int* iptr = &var;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

&gameUniqueID is a pointer, so you should be using %p, not %d, to output it in an NSLog.

Also, `hash` returns an NSUInteger (unsigned int) for which you should be using %u, not %d.

Answer (score 1):

`&gameUniqueID` is the address of the variable `gameUniqueID`.